# Azure VPN Gateway (S2S) disabling Replay Detection

Tags: vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking, fortigate

I'm running an Azure VPN Gateway (VpnGw1, gen1, Route-based) and trying to connect a S2S connection to a Fortigate gateway. The connection is losing connectivity every so hours and I'm wondering if I can turn off Replay Detection as a possible solution.

To my knowledge this is enabled by default (I assume for security reasons) but I can't find a setting (via powershell) to turn this off. 
If this is not possible on my gen1-gateway, is it possible on gen2, policy-based or other SKU's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replay detection is not a tunable parameter for Azure VPN Gateways at this time.  This page provides a link for all elements that are tunable via an IPSec/IKE Policy:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-ipsecikepolicy-rm-powershell#part-1---workflow-to-create-and-set-ipsecike-policy